# Find $ \mathbb P \{ 2X + 3Y \gt 2 \}$, given the CDFs of $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, exponential-distribution

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with $F_X(x) = 2e^{-2x}, x \gt 0,$ and $F_Y(y) = 3e^{-3y}, y \gt 0.$

Find $ \mathbb P \{ 2X + 3Y \gt 2  \}$.

**SOLUTION:**

The solution states that $2X \sim 2\text{Expo}(2) \sim \text{Expo}(1)$ and $2Y \sim 3\text{Expo}(3) \sim \text{Expo}(1)$ and proceeds from there by identifying the sum of the two with a gamma-distributed random variable. This, of course, implies that $X \sim \text{Expo}(2)$ and $Y \sim \text{Expo}(3)$. However, what's given above in the statement of the problem I take to be the CDFs of these random variables (because of the capital "$F$"s), *not* the PDFs. And so, differentiating the above (to obtain the PDFs), we have

$$f_X(x) = -4e^{-2x} \text{ and } f_Y(y) = -9e^{-3y}  $$

which are obviously not the PDFs of two exponentially distributed random variables with parameters $2$ and $3$, respectively. Is this mistake, or is this there some "trick" I'm missing here?

Comment: "what's given above in the statement of the problem I take to be the CDFs of these random variables" Then you should be concerned that these functions assume values >1, no? OK, the choice of symbols $F_X$ and $F_Y$ was squarely unfortunate but the interpretation is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the given functions "$F_X$" and "$F_Y$" must be density functions. If they were CDF's, they must be non decreasing. However, both of them are decreasing. It must be a mistake!

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. It might've been an attempt to mislead the reader; I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

For finding out the sum of two independent exponentially distribyted random variables.Just use the transformation $X=U-V$ and $Y=V$ and find the joint pdf of $U$ and $V$ $$f_{U,V}(u,v)=\begin{cases} e^{-(u-v)}. e^{- v}.1&\text{if $0<u-v<\infty\,\,\,\,$ $0<v<\infty\;\;$ $0<u<\infty$}\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$
just integrate with respect to $v$ t get the pdf of $U$ i.e 
$$f_U(u)=\int_{0}^ue^{-u}dv\,\,\,\,\,\,\,,0<u<\infty$$
Thus u get $$f_U(u)=ue^{- u}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,0<u<\infty$$
Just use this pdf of the sum of two independent exponential random variables.and just find the probability by integrating $$P(U>2)=\int_{2}^\infty f_U(u)du $$
Let me also clear the fact that what you have been given is not the Cdf its actually the pdf..you can check that by verifying the properties of cdf and pdf

Comment: Right. Knowing that these are PDFs makes the problem quite easy; I was just confused about the notation, as it opposes convention. However, you're right, I should've confirmed whether or not these could even possibly be CDFs, which they can't (they're decreasing functions, for one). I don't know if the intention here was to "trick" the viewer, or what; but it's certainly a bit misleading.